# BigQuery - Finding the last Thursday of every month

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am looking for the fourth Thursday of every previous month. This query works for most of the time. However, there are months that have five Thursdays. (i.e: August, November..etc)

```
DECLARE days_in_current_month DEFAULT(
  DATE_DIFF(
    DATE_ADD(DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), MONTH), INTERVAL 1 MONTH),
    DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), MONTH),
    DAY
  ));

DECLARE days_in_previous_month DEFAULT ABS(
  DATE_DIFF(
    DATE_SUB(DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), MONTH), INTERVAL 1 MONTH),
    DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), MONTH),
    DAY
  ));


SELECT
CASE
  WHEN days_in_current_month = 31 AND days_in_previous_month = 30 THEN DATE(DATE_SUB(DATE_TRUNC(DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE()), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), WEEK(THURSDAY)), INTERVAL 7 DAY))
  WHEN days_in_current_month = 30 AND days_in_previous_month = 31 THEN DATE(DATE_TRUNC(DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE()), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), WEEK(THURSDAY)))
  WHEN days_in_current_month = 30 AND days_in_previous_month = 30 THEN DATE(DATE_TRUNC(DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE()), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), WEEK(THURSDAY)))
ELSE DATE(DATE_SUB(DATE_TRUNC(DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE()), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), WEEK(THURSDAY)), INTERVAL 7 DAY))
END AS scheduled
```

How do I make this **dynamically** show the fourth Thursday of every month.

I initially thought the task was to find the LAST Thursday of the month. So I simply used

```
SELECT DATE(DATE_TRUNC(DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE()), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), WEEK(THURSDAY)))
```

Then,

```
SELECT DATE(DATE_SUB(DATE_TRUNC(DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE()), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), WEEK(THURSDAY)), INTERVAL 7 DAY))
```

I realize I want it to only show the FOURTH Thursday of every month (for months that have 5 Thursdays). I used this on November ( Current_date() changed to '2023-12-07' ). It works but, the rest of the months it will show the wrong date.

How do I make it work Dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

use below

```
select 
  21 + last_day(date_trunc(date_sub(current_date, INTERVAL x month), month), WEEK(FRIDAY)) day
from unnest(generate_array(0,12)) x
order by day desc
```

with output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
with calendar as (
  select cal_date 
  from unnest(generate_date_array('2020-01-01',current_date, interval 1 day)) as cal_date
),
thursdays as (
  select * from calendar where format_date('%A',cal_date) = 'Thursday'
)
select * from thursdays
qualify row_number() over(partition by date_trunc(cal_date, month) order by cal_date) = 4
```