# How to get the date for 4th Friday of November in any year using big query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

How to get the date of fourth Friday of November in any year in Big Query?
Month will always be 11 and day is 4th Friday.

Comment: Don't know bigquery, but I'd assume you can get the weekday of 1st of November, and then just calculate how many days to add to get to 1st Friday, and add 21 days.

Comment: yes. similar to approach in https://stackoverflow.com/a/77084685/5221944

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approach

```
SELECT Year, DATE_ADD(DATE(Year, 11, 1), INTERVAL dayOffset DAY) AS Friday
FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(2020, 2025)) AS Year, 
  UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0, 29)) AS dayOffset 
WHERE EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM DATE(Year, 11, 1) + INTERVAL dayOffset DAY) = 6 
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Year) = 4
```

with output

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Mikhail. It is awesome solution.  I am very grateful for this, Can you please explain last line in detail

Comment: last line takes care of selecting only 4th Fridays in November for each year!

Answer (score 0):

Try this script:

```
WITH DateGenerator AS (
  SELECT DATE(DATE_ADD(DATE <your_year_here>, INTERVAL 10 MONTH)) AS date
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 7 DAY) AS date
  FROM DateGenerator
  WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date) = 11
  LIMIT 4
)
SELECT MAX(date) AS fourth_friday
FROM DateGenerator;
```

- Replace `<your_year_here>` with the year for which you want to find
  the fourth Friday in November.
- The `LIMIT 4` ensures that the CTE stops after the fourth Friday.
- The MAX(date) in the final SELECT statement gives you the date of the
  fourth Friday in November for the specified year.

Comment: I am getting this error while running your script.

WITH DateGenerator AS (
  SELECT DATE(DATE_ADD(DATE (2022), INTERVAL 10 MONTH)) AS date
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 7 DAY) AS date
  FROM DateGenerator
  WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date) = 11
  LIMIT 4
)
SELECT MAX(date) AS fourth_friday
FROM DateGenerator;

Error
"Table "DateGenerator" must be qualified with a dataset (e.g. dataset.table)."